# D3 mouse event handler deprecated

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

We have a heatmap for which I am trying to create a tooltip. The example we were using when building mine had d3.mouse which is deprecated in the D3 version we use with React. We saw different alternatives such as d3.pointer(), but we haven't managed to get it working.
I have attached below the small part of the code where the d3.mouse would have gone. Is there any way to position the tooltip with respect to the mouse without using the deprecated d3.mouse?

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
                .data(data, d => {return (d.group+':'+d.variable)})
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", d => { return x(d.group) })
                .attr("y", d => { return y(d.variable) })
                .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
                .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
                .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
                .on("mouseover", (d,i,e) => {
                    tooltip.html("The value is : " + i.value)
                        .style('opacity', .9)
                        .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
                })
                .on("mouseout", () => {
                    tooltip.style('opacity', 0)
                        .style('left', '0px');
                })
```

Comment: You can actually just reference the event's clientX and clientY. You no longer have to use d3.mouse. However, what version of D3 are you using? Between V5 and V6, handling events changed.

Comment: I am using React V6 right now. I tried using PageX and PageY, but they don't give me the correct values. I did not know ClientX existed. I will give it a try.